# Linux untar with prefix

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple tar's that I want to untar into a folder and then append a prefix to them. The problem is that I don't know the name of the folder that it would create on the target system since these are build tar's and they have a date-timestamp inside. Here is what I tried -

```
tar xfz <filename>-*.tar.gz -C $UNTAR_LOCATION
```

so this creates a folder like this `20140909-0900` on the target `UNTAR_LOCATION`. How can I append a prefix to the date-timestamp ?

Note - there will be multiple folders with different date-timestamps under `UNTAR_LOCATION` for which I want to add the same prefix.

Answer (score 1):

With versions of tar that support the `--transform` flag you should be able to use something like this:

```
tar -xzf <filename>-*.tar.gz -C "$untar_location" --transform='s,^,prefix,'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with pax, the portable archiver:

```
gzip -cd filename.tar.gz | ( cd "$untar_location" && pax -r -s,^,prefix-, )
```

Most implementations of `pax` also has a `-z` option to filter through gzip, in which case it becomes

```
( cd "$untar_location" && pax -zrf filename.tar.gz -s,^,prefix-, )
```